# Autoresize not working in xib

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xib, autoresize

I made simple design in `.xib`, deployment target for my app is **iOS 5**
My view doesn't resizes, when i run my app in simulator or device.

here is snapshot of my `.xib` file..

[image]
When i try to run my app in simulator, it runs properly in the simulator of 4", but it does not resizes, when i run my app in the simulator of 3.5". **Autoresize subview** property is checked.

Here is snapshot of my `Simulaotrs`, first screenshot is for 3.5" and second for 4"..

[image]
***Thanks in advance.***

Comment: set size =None to Retina 3.5 Full Screen

Comment: Did you integrate scrollview ? So you can scroll page. Because it's not possible to view whole view because of Navigation & tabbar controller

Comment: It is not scrollView, it is only simple view

Comment: For easy solution, Why don't you create two seperate Xib's one for iPhone4/4S and another iPhone5.You don't have to manage programatically.

Comment: show us the autoresize values for the views and its subviews, please. it could say much more than that image.

Comment: @Krunal, in that case set the root view **all** autoresize property `On`, and keep the subviews' property the same as is.

Comment: autoresize property is `On` every where..

Comment: What are you expecting to happen on the two different screen sizes? You've got a matrix of icons in there, that isn't something that can be rearranged with autoresizing masks. Can you edit the question to explain what you'd _like_ to see in each simulator? For example, if you want all the icons to be closer together in the 3.5" screen, that's not going to be possible with autoresizing masks.

Comment: yes, i want all the icons to be close together in 3.5" simulator and it should also fir in 4" simulator. i have checked **autoresize subviews**

Comment: When designing a single Xib for use on multiple screens, I find it easier to start with the 3.5" screen, add the status bar, nav bar, and tab bar when applicable, and then set the Xib to FreeForm.  You now know how the Xib will look in it's smallest form.  After that, it's just a matter of Autoresize settings, and whether the parent view affects resizes it's children.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to autoresize and autoorder the icons referencing to the upper view, try to play either with the layout tab
[image: layout]

or create for each layout own .xib ;)

Comment: Good suggestion from you, do u know how to add space between icon and it's label ?

Comment: in my app I set this programatically. maybe you can use a container view? or simply a UICollectionView and set the rowheight ^^ but while you do so, you can build a second and third .xib file. if you dont intend to extend the list but let it static, it's the easiest way ;) if you know that the number of items will extend, than better use the collection view. if dont like it or have to use it in IOS 5.1 and lower, I can give you my solution for something similar ;)

Answer (score 7):

could you please use next setting in your .xib file (416 = 480 - 20 (width for status bar) - 44(width for nav bar)
[image]

[image: 416 = 480 - 20 (width for status bar) - 44(width for nav bar)]

if you want icon in the top on iPhone 5 use next setting for icons:
[image]
[image]

if you want icon in the bottom on iPhone 5 use next setting for icons:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Good suggestion from you, do u know how to add space between icon and it's label ?

Comment: label  - is it label in inside button or button with icon and label - it is different elements?

Comment: if first variant you can use contentEdgeInsets, imageEdgeInsets, titleEdgeInsets properties in UIButton. If you use second variant you should use right autoresizingMask property in your label

Comment: They are different elements, i placed label below button.

Comment: You can set the same autoresizingMask property to labels as buttons

Comment: Thank you very much for help, Alexander, because of this behaviour of ScrollView. I am just saved.

Answer (score 3):

Check whether you have unchecked the Autolayout option in `.xib` file..[image]

Comment: can you post the screen shot

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar effect I wanted to achieve with a grid of buttons. I think you'll find the autoresizing that iOS 5 supports simply won't do it. In the end I had two Storyboards, one for iOS 6 devices and another for iOS 5. My App Delegate then checked to see if the main view responded to the `constraints` method of UIView (which tells you if it supports the new iOS 6 constraints-based layout) and loaded the relevant Storyboard.

Something like this in your `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method:

```
if (![self.window.rootViewController.view respondsToSelector:@selector(constraints)]) {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_BC_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *rootController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self.window setRootViewController:rootController];
}
```

The iOS 6 Storyboard is loaded by default, but this overrides it with the backward compatible one if need be. The backward compatible Storyboard is manually set out for a 3.5" display only since the iPhone 5 will only run iOS 6 minimum, and thus the backward compatible Storyboard will not need to run on a 4" display.

Setting up the backward compatible Storyboard didn't take long - just duplicate your iOS 6 one that uses constraints, then set it to a 3.5" display, turn constraints off and fix up the views.

An alternative could be to layout the icons programmatically based on the screen dimensions. The advantage of this is you could design it to accommodate any screen size, but the downside is this is probably going to be a lot more effort.

[Edit]
Noted you're using a .xib rather than Storyboards, but the theory is the same. Check if UIView responds to `constraints` then load the appropriate NIB (.xib) file accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is so easy.
 
Add UIVIew on your super view and then add all icons onto them like this 
(notice the view size starting from the navigation controller to the tab bar)
[image]

This subview (the one has your icons) should have these autoresizing masks
[image]

- And your icons should have the same autoresizing masks.

Answer (score 2):

You can get reference from [Ray WenderLich example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2). Very simple explanation of autoLayout with example along with it.It will describe you every line where you are doing mistake.If you have enabled Autolayout then constraints must show in left side while selecting View.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it you have a couple of options depending on how your layout is set up and how you want to solve it.

If you are using Autolayout, there would be Contraints on your elements, and that could make it impossible to display all your elements in the view, even if you use resize. They just won't fit. So in that scenario, I suggest you use a scrollview in the 480 resolution to make your view being able to be displayed.

[image: Autolayout disabled]

In your .h file, make an IBOutlet to your view:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;
```

In your .m file, set up like so.

```
//Add scrollview
UIScrollView *scrollView=(UIScrollView *)self.view;
scrollView.contentSize=self.contentView.frame.size;
[self.view addSubview:self.contentView];
```

Another work around making it possible for you to place your elements wherever you feel like with different spacings etc. would be to make two different .xib files and set it up like this in you ViewController:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0)
        {
            //Use iPhone5 VC
            self = [super initWithNibName:@"RootViewController-568h" bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        }
        else{
            //Use Default VC
            self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

This is if you call your ViewController `RootViewController`  and this way you are safe if they do decide to expand the screen size on the coming iPhone5s or iPhone6. It won't look great but at least it won't crash the app.