# App doesn't fit on iPhone 4

Tags: ios, layout

I've built an app on Xcode(5.1.1) and it looks fine on the iPhone 5 but the bottom appears to be cut off on iPhone 4...how do I fix this? Auto layout is checked for each and every view controller.

Comment: You will need to add constraint to your each control.

Comment: Checking alone Auto-Layout is not enough, you have to set the constraints for the sub views in your view

Comment: Its better to follow these links,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832532/autoresize-not-working-in-xib

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341797/i-have-a-xib-file-that-i-am-trying-to-resize-for-iphone-5

Comment: Be careful with @Shiva Kumar Ganthi's links, they aren't autolayout-oriented.

Comment: It depends on how you would like the views to be layout in the 3.5 inch screen. The easiest way would be use a UIScrollView rather than a UIView, so that it will scroll in 3.5 inch screen

Comment: @Shadowfiend If I just change the class of UIView to UIScrollView will that affect my layout?

Comment: If you set the autolayout constraint properly, it wouldn't affect your layout. @user3140562

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to automatically set the autolayout :

[image]

If it's not good enough, you'll have to set the constraints yourself :

- Official doc : https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html
- Ray Wenderlich tutorial : http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1